# Nested for each to compare two arrays doesn't match final item

Tags: ruby, list, foreach, compare

I have two files of user-guids that I need to compare.

`FileA` contains a list sent from a client and contains duplicates and `FileB` is a list of user-guids from our system.

My first task is to make sure that our system has all the unique user-guids from the client's system (ie `FileB` contains all the user-guids that are in `FileA`). After that I need to determine how many of the user-guids in our system are NOT in the client's list but that's another task and is unrelated.

The files contain one guid per line so I'm reading them into arrays and using a nested for each to compare them.

**Here is my code:**

```
# Open each file of users
FileA = File.open("file_a.txt")
FileB = File.open("file_b.txt")

# Turn file_a into an array with only unique values and close the file
file_a_array = IO.readlines(FileA).uniq
FileA.close

# Turn the local file into an array, we already know each line is unique
file_b_array = IO.readlines(FileB)
FileB.close

file_a_array.each do |i|
    file_b_array.each do |j|
        if i == j
            puts i
        end
    end
end
```

This code again is meant to return all the matches, but in reality I was seeing all the matches except one, incidentally the last one on the list of FileB.

In trying to guess at why I was not seeing the last match I noticed that the FileA had an empty line at the end of the file but FileB did not.

**Here's an example:**

```
FileA Contents:
guid_a
guid_b
guid_c
guid_d
[empty line]

FileB Contents:
guid_a
guid_aa
guid_b
guid_bb
guid_c
guid_cc
guid_d
```

Notice each file contains `guid_d` but the results of running my code was returning the following as the matches:

```
guid_a
guid_b
guid_c
```

When I added an extra line to the end of `FileB` suddenly I was getting the full set.

**So the question is why?**

Comment: Did the close votes want to explain the reason this should be closed? I gave a pretty detailed question. Sorry I'm not a Ruby genius.

Comment: I've rewritten the question since others seemed to think it wasn't clear what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding my own answer because the two that are here while technically both correct aren't very descriptive and didn't lead me to my solution. Only after I figured it out on my own did I finally understand what they were saying.

When I was loading my files into arrays using `IO.readlines` the contents of each array item contained a newline character `\n`.

So going off the example in my original question, the reason `guid_d` wasn't being matched is because in file_a_array, the value being used for comparison was `guid_d\n` and the value in file_b_array was `guid_d`. The line of FileB with `guid_d` did not contain a newline character until I added it by adding the empty last line.

Comment: You can use the `chomp` function to sanitize the input, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `chomp` function.

This function removes trailed line breaks from a string is meant to be used to sanitize input from files. As you mention in your answer Ruby reads lines including the linebreak

> the reason guid_d wasn't being matched is because in `file_a_array`, the value being used for comparison was `guid_d\n` and the value in `file_b_array` was `guid_d`.

Use `chomp` to fix this

```
"guid_d\n".chomp # => "guid_d"
"guid_d".chomp # => "guid_d"
```

Change your program to use

```
IO.readlines(...).map(&:chomp)...
```

Comment: @sanpaco glad to hear! Best mark this answer the checkmark then.

Answer (score 0):

You have left out some important information about the file format and how you were reading in the contents, so I am going to make an educated guess that your comparisons are including a newline or return character. Therefore the last item in the list was different until you added the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is why did I need to have an empty line in order for the last item to show up in my results of matched items?

Because then the last item will also end with a newline like all the others.